# Expectation value of $x$ in infinite square well

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm working on a infinite square well problem and I have the wavefunction:

$$
\Psi(x,0) = \begin{cases} A\sin^3{(\frac{\pi x}{a})}&\,{\rm if}\ 0\leq x\leq a \\
0&\,{\rm otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

which I can express like this:

$$
\Psi(x,0) = c_1\psi_1 + c_3\psi_3
$$

where

$$
\psi_1 = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin{(\frac{\pi x}{a})} \\
\psi_3 = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin{(\frac{3\pi x}{a})} 
$$

and so,

$$
\Psi(x,t) = c_1\psi_1e^{-\frac{iE_1t}{\hbar}} + c_3\psi_3e^{-\frac{iE_3t}{\hbar}} \\
|\Psi(x,t)|^2 = (c_1\psi_1)^2 + (c_3\psi_3)^2+2c_1c_3\psi_1\psi_3\cos{\bigg(\frac{(E_3-E_1)t}{\hbar}\bigg)}
$$

I want to know the expectation value of x, $\langle x \rangle$ as a function of time. However after evaluating $\int_{0}^{a} x|\Psi(x,t)|^2 dx$, I got $\frac{a}{2}$ instead of some function of time.

I thought the first ($x(c_1\psi_1)^2$) and the second term ($x(c_3\psi_3)^2$) of the integral should be zero since it's an odd function but I get $\frac{a}{2}c_n^2$ on either terms. The cross term also gives me zero after evaluating the integral.

May I get some hint on what I did wrong/missed?

Comment: Terms like $x \psi_1^2$ will not be $0$ by parity since you are not integrating from $-a$ to $a$ but over an interval $0$ to $a$ that is not parity-symmetric.  The key is whether the cross term $x \psi_1\psi_3$ averages to $0$ under $\int_0^a$.  If yes then the average will not depend on time.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I see, so I can just write <x>(t) = a/2 and since it's a constant that means the position of the particle is expected to be at that place at any times the measurement is made?